# Ajax call does not seem to recognize my file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a very simple HTML file which has one button. When this button is clicked the function loadDoc() runs in the javascript file (ajax.js). The div with ID ajax_text gets changed into 'clicked'. So far so good.

Now I am trying to make ajax call to a php document. The php document should echo "Hello World!". I am trying to show this message by using an alert (alert(msg)). The php document is located in the same folder as my HTML document.

What am I doing wrong in my ajax call??

I already tried multiple urls such as:
- 'http://localhost/ajax_info.php'
- the complete path to the file
- 'localhost/ajax_info.php'

etc. etc.

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="name">John</div>
    <div id="demo">
      <h2>Header 2</h2>
      <button type="button" onclick="loadDoc()">Change Content</button>
    </div>
    <script src="jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
    <script src="ajax.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function loadDoc() {

document.getElementById('name').innerHTML = "Steven";

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'ajax_info.php',
        success: function(msg){
            alert(msg);
        }
    });
 }
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php  echo "Hello World"; ?>
```

Comment: use chrome's developer tools to analyze if the request is actually made and what's the response. Also use "error" callback in your $.ajax call to see what's the error

Comment: FYI: success: alert("Alert Box") does work so it seems it just doesn't work when i use success: function(data){ alert(data);}

Comment: are you sure success callback is even called? add error callback or use chrome's dev tools

Comment: ..this is why you should add the error callback (kinda the same as success, but just `error: function(response) { console.log(response); },`)

Comment: cann you call the php script directly? (by typing `http://localhost/ajax_info.php` into browser)

Comment: You should add an error handler to your ajax call, so you can see what goes wrong. Obviously, something goes wrong, otherwise the success handle would be called and the alter would pop up.

Comment: @jeff error: function(response){alert(response)} gives me the following output: [object Object]. Yes I can call the php script directly

Comment: Your code as it stands does work. I just ran it. Where is your file ajax_info.php in relation to where you are calling your index file. It will be a path issue in your ajax url, as will be shown in your browsers developer tools in the console.

Comment: @TimBrownlaw ajax_info.php and index.html are in the same folder (in the htdocs of xampp folder)

Comment: @TimBrownlaw this is the console error I got: Failed to load file:///C:/Users/Bart/xampp/htdocs/ajax_info.php: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

Comment: @TimBrownlaw now that I changed the url to: 'http://localhost/ajax_info.php' it gives this error: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: following your second to last comment: the reason likely will be that you don't call your html correctly (`http://localhost/myhtml.html`), but via file-explorer like `file://somefolders/myhtml.html`

Comment: solved it by adding header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); to my php file

Comment: @Jeff You are right! If I type in http://localhost/ajax.html and run it (even without having header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); in my php file) it runs! Thanks all you guys for the comments!

Comment: glad that this solution (with access-control-allow-origin) works now, but it surely should _not_ be the final solution, as you now allow everyone (when you put that script live) to access it, therefor you're open for cross-site scripting attacks.

Comment: @BartBoersma - yes but these are files on your local server and you are not requesting files from other domains... So you shouldn't need to... What is the URL you are using? localhost/index.html? I assumed you have an index.html file with the html. Your ajax.js file ( along with your jquery file ) and your ajax_info.php file. 4 Files in total or have I assumed wrong.?

Comment: I'll post it as an answer then..

Comment: I find you include `<script>`s after closing the `</body>` .. cut/past it before `</body>` not after it

Comment: :) Ahhh so it was the never mentioned ajax.html file... I just called it index.html when I ran it before and got it working... 27 minutes ago :)

Answer (score 1):

It looks as if you call your html page as file from your file-explorer, but not - as you should - via your web-server.
If your address in the browser has `file://somefolders/myhtml.html` your php script (well, actually the server) will say "hello, that's not where I am!" -> It throws "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access."

Now you can tell your server "Nah, don't bother, I'll just allow everyone!"
This is what you do when setting the `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');`

*But* your initial problem was that the html-file wasn't called at the same origin, namely your (local) server.

So if you type in your browser's address bar `http://localhost/ajax.html` and *don't* just double click the file in file-explorer it should work, because now they both (html and php) live in the same environment.

Answer (score 0):

try to write the javascript code inside the page that has html.
it should works .

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>

<body>


<div id="name">John</div>

<div id="demo">
  <h2>Header 2</h2>
  <button type="button" onclick="loadDoc()">Change Content</button>
</div>


<script src="jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
<script>
  function loadDoc() {
  document.getElementById('name').innerHTML = "Steven";

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'ajax_info.php',
        success: function(msg){
            alert(msg);
        }
    });
  }
</script>
```

Comment: That assumes that all the files are in the same folder. So jquery-3.2.1.js and ajax_info.php have to be in the same folder as the file above. There are No Paths specified to any other folder.